# A Divide by Zero results in a crash

Tags: c

This will create an error for attempting to divide by zero, if this error is not caught by the error handling capabilities of the language, unexpected results can occur:

```
static void aspect_adjust_packed4444_scanline_c( uint8_t *output,
                                                 uint8_t *input, 
                                                 int width,
                                                 double pixel_aspect )
{
    double i;
    int prev_i = 0;
    int w = 0;

    pixel_aspect = 1.0 / pixel_aspect;

    for( i = 0.0; i < width; i += pixel_aspect )
    {
        uint8_t *curin = input + ((int) i)*4;

        if( !prev_i )
        {
                output[ 0 ] = curin[ 0 ];
                output[ 1 ] = curin[ 1 ];
                output[ 2 ] = curin[ 2 ];
                output[ 3 ] = curin[ 3 ];
        }
        else
        {
            int avg_a = 0;
            int avg_y = 0;
            int avg_cb = 0;
            int avg_cr = 0;
            int pos = prev_i * 4;
            int c = 0; /* assignment: Assigning: "c" = "0" */
            int j;

            for( j = prev_i; j <= (int) i; j++ )
            {
                avg_a += input[ pos++ ];
                avg_y += input[ pos++ ];
                avg_cb += input[ pos++ ];
                avg_cr += input[ pos++ ];
                c++;
            }
            output[ 0 ] = avg_a / c;  /* Division or modulo by zero */
            output[ 1 ] = avg_y / c;  /* Division or modulo by zero */
            output[ 2 ] = avg_cb / c; /* Division or modulo by zero */
            output[ 3 ] = avg_cr / c; /* Division or modulo by zero */
        }
        output += 4;
        prev_i = (int) i;
        w++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the program to do ?

Comment: What's the result supposed to be if c is Zero?

Comment: In a portable way? Check for zero before doing it...

Comment: Show at least a little effort by indenting the code properly.

Comment: That the app crashes when you divide by zero is expected behavior. You have to fix the cause of the illegal division.

Comment: `"error is not caught by the error handling capabilities of the language"` Lol. This is C, friend. *You* are the error handling capabilities. No runtime safety net here.

Comment: As you have a "c++" inside your loop c will be at least 1

Comment: A C program crashing when dividing a number by zero is expected behavior.  The language is not there to do the work for you. You must detect the division by zero and protect against it.

Comment: I can't find any sequence when c will be 0 at the division. The for loop is always executed at least once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide by zero leads to undefined behavior.

> #### C11 §6.5.5 Multiplicative operators
>
> The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the `%` operator is the remainder. **In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.**

There is no exception handling in C, you need to protect from it yourself in some way:

```
if (b != 0)
    c = a / b;
```

or use the short circuit:

```
b && (c = a / b);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, c will be zero only if this loop is not executed. You can either check for the condition or initialize c with 1 instead.

```
 int c = 0; /* assignment: Assigning: "c" = 0 */
 int j;

 for( j = prev_i; j <= (int) i; j++ ) {
     avg_a += input[ pos++ ];
     avg_y += input[ pos++ ];
     avg_cb += input[ pos++ ];
     avg_cr += input[ pos++ ];
     c++;
 }
 output[ 0 ] = avg_a / c;  /* Division or modulo by zero */
 output[ 1 ] = avg_y / c;  /* Division or modulo by zero */
 output[ 2 ] = avg_cb / c; /* Division or modulo by zero */
 output[ 3 ] = avg_cr / c; /* Division or modulo by zero */
```

However, it is more important to understand the logic first and intention of the program.

It is the expected behaviour of the program to crash on divide by zero in C.